# Are there any surviving maps from the Delhi Sultanate?

Tags: india, maps

Are there any surviving maps of the [Delhi Sultanate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delhi_Sultanate) that were made in India during that era?  I'm having a very hard time finding any maps surviving from that period of Indian history that actually come from India.

Comment: +1, interesting question. I wonder what are some of the oldest maps **of** India made **in** India.

Answer (score 1):

I hope the Wiki link in your post itself contains the map of the Sultan Empire in India. I have provided some links Which I have referred to know about History of Delhi and Sultan Empire.

1. [The Delhi Sultanate (1206-1526)](http://www.facts-about-india.com/the-delhi-sultanate.php)
2. [History of Delhi](http://www.mapsofindia.com/delhi/history.html)
3. [Slave Dynasty](http://www.mapsofindia.com/history/slave-dynasty.html)
4. [Delhi Sultanate](http://www.iloveindia.com/history/medieval-india/delhi-sultunate/)

This may helps you.

Thanks

Comment: I don't believe any of those were made "during that era". Still, based on the lack of response my guess is there aren't any, so this is the best the questioner is liable to get.